# How to make a matrix with exactly two numeric values per row and NAs elsewhere?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I am trying to create a mock matrix/dataframe which includes two numerical values per row and NAs everywhere else. I am trying to mock a money allocation experiment with 5 factors (columns), between 2 of which the subject has to divide up their money.

The first three lines would look like this:

```
NA NA 30 NA 70
25 NA NA 75 NA
60 40 NA NA NA
...
```

I am envisioning 100 lines or so. The row total should always add up to 100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like the following:

```
set.seed(5)

# Create matrix of NAs

m <- matrix(ncol = 5, nrow = 5)

nr <- nrow(m)
nc <- ncol(m)

# Create replacement indices (two unique row indices)
idx <- cbind(rep(sequence(nr), each = 2), c(replicate(nr, sample(nc, 2, replace = FALSE))))

# Create replacement values
vals <- c(replicate(nc, c({x <- sample(100, 1)}, 100 - x)))

m[idx] <- vals  

m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   NA   28   72   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   50   NA   NA   50
[3,]   32   NA   68   NA   NA
[4,]   NA   NA   56   44   NA
[5,]   73   NA   NA   NA   27
```

Comment: The rows don't total to 100 for each row.

Comment: @TeaTree - sorry, missed that requirement, will edit.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I came up with, trying to generalize a solution. If you wish to have 2 numbers per row out of 5 columns with integers that add to 100. This assumes of course that `num_cols` is greater than `numbers_per_row`.

```
set.seed(123)

row_sum <- 100
num_rows <- 100
num_cols <- 5
numbers_per_row <- 2

rand.sum <- function(n){
  x <- sort(sample(row_sum, n-1))
  c(x, row_sum) - c(0,x)
}

do.call("rbind", lapply(1:num_rows, function(x) sample(c(rep(NA, num_cols - numbers_per_row), rand.sum(numbers_per_row)))))
```

**Output**

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
  [1,]   NA   NA   69   31   NA
  [2,]   57   43   NA   NA   NA
  [3,]   NA   90   NA   10   NA
  [4,]   57   NA   43   NA   NA
  [5,]   NA   NA   28   NA   72
  [6,]   83   NA   NA   NA   17
  [7,]   NA   NA   NA   76   24
  [8,]   NA   74   NA   26   NA
  [9,]   NA   NA   73   NA   27
 [10,]   24   NA   NA   NA   76
 ...
```